# Defining which field was changed in a grid

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to identify on a kendo UI grid which field was altered on a row edit?

Right now I am sending the entire row to the server that was changed. I would like to send
the request to the server to also include a variable holding the name
of the field that was edited.

1. Is something like that supported by kendo or
2. is there a work around for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. However the grid API should allow this to be implemented. Check the [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#edit) and [save](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#save) events. In there you can [listen](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#bind) to [changes](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#change-event) of the model instance which is currently being edit. Here is a quick example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   edit: function(e) {
     e.model.unbind("change", model_change).bind("change", model_change);
   }
});

function model_change(e) {
  var model = this;
  var field = e.field;
  // store somewhere the field and model
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/38mHb/3/ . Wouldn't it be easier to catch the field like that and set it in the default "update" kendo function ?

Comment: The "change" event of the grid is raised during selection.

Comment: This above (that i posted in the link) code seems to work, although i am facing a small problem with the cellIndex.My cellIndex when selecting something is for example "25", so with this.columns[cellIndex];  my column variable stays undefined. This is happening as the real index is different from the view index of the grid.  In other words, i have total 30 fields, 5 of them are visible to the grid, while the rest is hidden. Atanas, i want that information to be send to the server only when the confirmation button for the update is pressed.That is why i mentioned about the kendo update function